# factoring cubic polynomial equation using Cramer's rule.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

1) I have question about factoring cubic polynomials. In my note it says "Any polynomial equation with positive powers whose coefficients add to 0 will have a root of 1. Another, if sum of the coefficients of the even powers = sum of coefficient of the odd powers, -1 is a rood." However, all of my problems were solved with factor(x-1) if the coefficients add to 0 and vice versa. I am totally confused when to use  1, when to use -1. 
example:

x<sup>4</sup>+17x<sup>3</sup>-3x+k = 0

so the root is as follow:

a) 1 k = -49      b) -1  k = -12

2) 2nd questions is finding determinant 3X3 ,we repeat 1st and 2nd row and make 3 crisscross product the left and to the right. But i have no clue what is saying here. "where delta Dij = the (n-1)X(n-1) determinant former striking out row i and col j."
    example:

```
1 3 5 6 8
6 7 2 7 1
0-1 6 4 10
3 4 5 1 6 
8 7 9 4 -2

Dij = 6 7 2 1 
      0-1 6 10
      3 4 5 6
      8 7 9-2
for n = 3 what is value of Delta.
```

My questions is i do not understand which row and which column are referred in this. Any explaining would be highly appreciated.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the root is 1 the polynomial is divisible by x -1; if the root is -1 the polynomial is divisible by x + 1.  Unfortunately I'm getting k = -15 for the root of 1: adding the coefficients we have 1 + 17 -3 + k = 0 so 15 + k = 0. and k = -15.  I checked it out by actually dividing through by x -1.

For the second the coefficients of the even powers add to 1 + k.  The coefficients of the odd powers add to 17 - 3 = 14.  So 1 + k = 14 and k = 13.  Again, I double checked this with division.

The problem I see here is that you were not offered x = 1 k = 15 or x = -1 k = 13.  Did you give us the wrong polynomial?

---

Start with any matrix.  Then D$_{ij}$ is the determinant of a submatrix that you get by crossing out the ith row and jth column of the original matrix.  For example if A is a 3x3 matrix defined as

\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & i
\end{pmatrix}

The D$_{23} is the determinant of

\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
g & h 
\end{pmatrix}

which is ah-bg.  To get the determinant of the 3x3 matrix above you can use
$a*D_{11} - b*D_{12} + c*D_{13}$.

Comment: Can you explain more about crossing out the matrix(ith and jth row) I don't understand this. from my example above, 1st row is crossed out and 3rd column is crossed out. From Your example 2nd row and 3rd column is crossed out. Any difference in 3x3 matrix and higher like 5x5 matrix.

Comment: I crossed out 2nd row and 3rd column as an example of what D$_{23}$ is.  If you want $D_{12}$ you cross out the 1st row and 2nd column. Then below I showed you one way to compute the determinant of a 3x3 in terms of $D_{11}, D_{12}, D_{13}.$  Notice that a, b, c -- the first row -- are used as coefficients on the determinants of $D_{11}, D_{12}, D_{13}.$  So we computed the determinant of the 3x3 by expanding in terms of the 1st row of the matrix.  You can compute the determinant by expanding in terms of any row or column of the matrix (continued next comment).

Comment: If you were computing the determinant using the 2nd row, you would use $-d*D_{21} + e*D_{22} - f*D_{23}$.  This would get you the same answer as expanding by the first row.  Which row you use for the expansion is up to you, but sometimes, depending on the matrix, one row is much easier than the others, because it has a lot of 0's in it.

Comment: thanks lot for the explanation.